# eclipse crashing with intellisense

Tags: eclipse

Eclipese crashes on one (and only it appears) intellensense.

typing "Display.getW" (towards the Display.GetWidth() function) as I type W eclipse reproduceably crashes. Trying random other functions and classes yield no problems.

Any ideas as to what this might be?

```
Eclipse Info: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Build id: 20100218-1602 
Eclipse Galileo
```

Edit: Using windowsXP

Comment: WindowsXP, questioned edited.

Comment: I created a bug, which turned out to be a duplicate of an existing issue: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=283503

They say its fixed for 3.6 but I have not been able to verify that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only bugs related to a crash on auto-completion all mention Linux platform and an issue with xulrunner library.

See for instance [bug 236724](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=236724#c50):

> You don't need to download an older version of xulrunner since the problem is merely that the 64bit version of the library is being loaded rather than the 32bit library.
>   To rectify this, just add the following line to your **eclipse.ini** file which points to the 32bit version of the xulrunner library:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=<path_to_32bit_xulrunner_lib>
```

> On RHEL5 for example, the path would be `/usr/lib/xulrunner-1.9`.

So you would in this case either need an older version of xulrunner, or fixing its path.

On Windows, on the other hand, that may be a good opportunity to fill in a new bug report.

---

Update February 2012, [Raedwald](https://stackoverflow.com/users/545127/raedwald) mentions in the comments:

> - The relevant [Eclipse FAQ "Can I specify which XULRunner installation gets used?"](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#specifyxulrunner)
> - This can also fix the problem if you provide as the `XULRunnerPath` a path-name that does not point to an `xulrunner` library directory.
>     What happens is that Eclipse instead falls back to using an internal renderer.
>     I believe this is the only solution if your O/S (such as RedHat 5.8) upgrades you to a FireFox version that uses `xulrunner-2` but does not provide `webkitgtk`.

Comment: Bug filed. Review ID: 1809962

Comment: @paullb: strange... I can't find it. The latest bugs reported with "crash" in the sumary have an id of 318261 (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=318261), so "1809962" seems a bit too high.

Comment: Reveiw ID is the only identification I received in the email back from SunOracle. I don't know if it corresponds to a bug ticket or not.

Comment: @paullb: SunOracle! Right. Not an Eclipse bugs then. I would have had recommended opening a ticket at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/. Where id you opened yours? at http://bugs.sun.com ?

Comment: This can also fix the problem if you provide as the `XULRunnerPath` a path-name that does *not* point to an `xulrunner` library directory. What happens is that Eclipse instead falls back to using an internal redenderer. I believe this is the only solution if your O/S (such as RedHat 5.8) upgrades you to a Fire Fox version that uses `xulrunner-2` but does not provide `webkitgtk`.

Comment: The most relevant Eclipse FAQ is: http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#specifyxulrunner

Comment: @Raedwald good points. I have included them in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

This, and related problems, are caused by incompatibilities between Eclipse and `xulrunner`, which is a component of Fire Fox. I came across this problem today, after updating Fire Fox on my RHEL 5 development computer.

The "intellisense" (content assist) feature, and other features of Eclipse, are a rendering of HTML. Eclipse tries to hand-off this rendering work to a system component. If your web browser is Fire Fox, Eclipse traditionally uses `xulrunner`, which is intimately associated with Fire Fox. It does so by calling a C API through a native library. However, that API is subject to change by the Mozilla developers, and different versions of `xulrunner` have had incompatible APIs. In particular, Eclipse can not use "`xulrunner` 2", which is the version in recent versions of Fire Fox.

Newer versions of Eclipse try not to use `xulrunner` at all, but instead try to use `webkitgtk`. However, if that is not present, or Eclipse is configured not to use it, Eclipse will fall back to using `xulrunner`. Which can then crash, because Eclipse does not detect that the available `xulrunner` is incompatible. The Eclipse developers recognize this as a Bad Thing (it is [Bug 262929](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=262929)), but it no yet fixed (still in Eclipse 3.7).

Therefore, if `webkitgtk` is present on your computer, it might be better to tell Eclipse to use it. The [Eclipse FAQ says how to do this](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserwebkitgtk): set the Java property `org.eclipse.swt.browser.UseWebKitGTK` to `true`. You can do so in your `eclipse.ini` file (as told [elsewhere](http://blog.dmaggot.org/2010/12/using-webkit-and-eclipse-helios/)) by adding the line `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.UseWebKitGTK=true` at the end of the file.